# Change Fogbugz hover-over text in the wiki dropdown menu

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I would like to make a way to change the default hover-over text on the Wiki dropdown menu in Fogbugz. The default is just the name of the article (which you don't need twice) and I would like to replace it with the wiki article's tagline.

It looks like you could create a plug-in to get the information and send it to a JavaScript program but there doesn't seem to be an interface to change this.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the location you are talking about?

Comment: I had to upload it as a link because I do not have enough reputation points to directly upload it. But it's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this because I don't believe the tagline is available in any of the APIs.  However, I think the behavior you are trying to achieve should actually be the default and will create a case for it for Fog Creek.